# What are the acoustics of brass instrument pedal tones?

Tags: tone, acoustics, brass

The natural range of a standard Bb trumpet, for example, extends down to F# (i.e., concert E), but by adjusting one's embouchure and air, it's possible to produce lower pitches. Those lower pitches -- pedal tones -- have a distinctly different timbre than the natural tones of the instrument -- duller and less brassy, less stable. Through practice they can be made useable and their timbre brought closer to that of other notes, but....

**What is happening acoustically that makes pedal tones different?** (Or, maybe, why can't brass instruments naturally produce those pitches in the first place?)

---

**Related information**

- [Physics behind why a bugle can play several notes, while a whistle only plays one note](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/32640/physics-behind-why-a-bugle-can-play-several-notes-while-a-whistle-only-plays-on)
- [Playing 440 Hz, what are the harmonics for a trumpet? For a flute?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/107333/playing-440-hz-what-are-the-harmonics-for-a-trumpet-for-a-flute/107336#107336)
- [Trumpet Peculiar Frequency spectrum](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71607/trumpet-peculiar-frequency-spectrum)

Comment: Is this question limited to the trumpet, or does it apply to any valved brass instrument?

Comment: @Richard I limited it to trumpet only because I have no idea if the answer applies across brass instruments. If it does, the question should definitely be expanded. Let me know, and I'll rewrite

Comment: This point concerns all brass instruments.

Comment: Would you like an answer that starts from scratch with the vibrating modes of cylinders closed at one end or just jump right ahead to how the pedal tones fit into the resonances of a bell and mouthpiece instrument?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Quick answer: I think there's already a post covering the closed cylinder angle, so starting with the pedal tones seems best. Meanwhile, I'll see if I can track down the post I have in mind. If it's not there, expanding the question and answer seems appropriate.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  Will your answer apply to brass generally, or are there significant differences across the family? If yes to "brass generally", I'll expand the question in that regard, too.

Comment: @ToddWilcox [This answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71607/trumpet-peculiar-frequency-spectrum/71610#71610) discusses the closed cylinder issue. If you think the discussion is sufficient, maybe just include a sentence like "To read about the acoustics of ordinary tones, see here." If it's not sufficient, by all means include it here, and I'll edit the question to fit. (Understanding your post could be long and complex, I would humbly request you include some headers and such to make it easier for slow readers like me to peruse.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check here for the basics:

[Trumpet Peculiar Frequency spectrum](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71607/trumpet-peculiar-frequency-spectrum/71610#71610)

In the above answer, it’s stated that the trumpet’s “natural” overtone series of only odd harmonics is altered by the flare of the bell and the shape of the mouthpiece so that instead of being only the odd harmonics, it has essentially a normal harmonic series, but the fundamental is missing.

A pedal tone is a way to play the “missing” fundamental. Any resonant system has a lowest resonant frequency and for bell and mouthpiece brass it’s there, it’s just not as easy to sound as the first harmonic and much of the series above it.

It’s also a different embouchure from the rest so pedal tones aren’t as frequently taught because many believe learning to play then might create bad embouchure habits in the student.

One thing about the above linked answer I’d be careful of is the reference to the clarinet, which does only have its odd overtones but is also a conical bore instrument so I think there are some subtleties beyond the half closed cylinder model at work in the clarinet.

There’s a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedal_tone) on the topic also.

Everything I’ve found suggests the concept of pedal tones applies to all members of the brass family, namely cylindrical bore metal instruments with a flaring bell and hemispherical mouthpiece that are primarily played by sounding an overtone series along with valves that change the sounding length of the primary cylinder. The fact that the horn uses a different mouthpiece shape doesn’t exclude it from the category.

Comment: To confirm before I edit the OP, this applies across the brass family? Also, IMO, the last paragraph doesn't fit here, but would be valuable as a comment on the post it refers to.

Comment: @Aaron I know the trombone is the same in acoustics. I believe tuba and euphonium is the same. Of course sax is not really a brass instrument (which you probably know but for other readers). I’m not sure about French horn, because I know horn mouthpieces are often conical and less hemispherical. I suspect it’s the same or similar but I’m not sure.

Answer (score -1):

On any wind instrument, the basic idea behind the physics is that there's something vibrating at the front of the tube (the player's lips for brass instruments, the reed for reeded instruments, and air turbulence for flutes), which powers a vibration of air inside the tube, and the physics of constructive and destructive interference only allow a resonant frequency to ring out. The tone quality produced is determined by the spectrum of frequencies produced by the mouthpiece (and the skill of the player), refined by the characteristics of the resonator tube.

With trumpet pedal tones, you buzz a low frequency below the fundamental frequency of the tube, and "insist" on it hard enough that you overcome the physics of the resonator and force that pitch through. When this happens, the tube is no longer refining the tone as normal, and so the sound is just the mouthpiece buzz being [saxamaphoned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21x7KObESV0) through the horn.

Comment: Truthfully, you could have just written "saxamophone" and I still would have upvoted.

Comment: My understanding is the pedal tones are not below the fundamental frequency but ARE the fundamental frequencies. Not pedal tones are not fundamentals, they are overtones.

Comment: Yes, the pedal tone IS the fundamental.

Comment: @ToddWilcox No. Consider a note like F3. There is no length of tubing that makes this a fundamental.

Comment: MattPutnam I don’t understand your comment above. My calculations are that a simple cylinder closed at one end and open at the other has a fundamental frequency very close to F3 if it is only 19.5” long.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I don't know what you're consulting, but it's wrong. The remnants of the destroyed fundamental for the open fingering are around a (written) A2, but it's so fuzzy it's unusable. Even accepting that, there's no way to play Bb2-F3 as a resonant frequency of the instrument, with any valve combination.

Comment: I honestly don’t understand what you’re saying in your comments. They are going totally over my head.

Comment: @ToddWilcox With no valves pressed, you have the normal C-G-C-E etc., plus sorta that low A. Press 2nd valve, same thing down a half step, and so on. There is no fingering that gives a length of tube with a fundamental of F3.

Comment: You mean on a trumpet? I thought you were saying there’s no way to make a theoretical tube that has a fundamental of F3.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Why would I be talking like that? On any particular brass instrument, there's a lowest fundamental. Pedal tones are notes below this. They are NOT fundamentals.

Comment: @MattPutnam According to Wikipedia's [article on brass instrument pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_of_brass_instruments), the pedal tones are the fundamentals.

Answer (score -2):

Much the same as the acoustics of any other note.  Just somewhat harder to produce due to the proportions of the instrument and mouthpiece.

More interesting are the 'false' notes between pedal (written) C and F♯, bottom of the 'normal' range. There is a definite F fingered 1-2, E fingered 2-3 etc. (i.e. one fingering 'lower' than might be expected).   You have to force them, but they definitely exist and with practice can almost match the normal notes.

On trombone, the pedal notes are easier (wider tube, larger mouthpiece) and are routinely asked for.   The 'false' notes are also easier, but unlike the pedals are not normally asked for except as an 'extended technique'.

Modern trombones (especially bass trombones) have switchable extension tubing that enable  the lower range without trickery.  But the characteristic rasp of a smaller instrument's pedal tones is still useful.

Comment: This is very cool and deserves more visibility than it will get here. Opening a separate question....

Comment: New question opened.

Comment: "There is a definite F fingered 1-2, E fingered 2-3 etc." -- uh, no there isn't. Where is this coming from?

Comment: According to [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109006/what-are-brass-instrument-false-notes-and-how-are-they-played/109080#109080) the trumpet isn't capable of "false tones". Reading your post again, I think I understand the conflict. The notes below the "lowest" F# are "pedal tones" -- the subject of the question -- "false tones", which are related the bore-width vs. length ratio, aren't achievable on the trumpet, because its bore is too narrow.

Comment: @Aaron That post (my post) and the linked article don't say the trumpet isn't capable of false tones. I've never actually tried to play false tones on a trumpet.  I do know that pedal tones on a trumpet are difficult, but not impossible, so false tones may be possible as well.

Comment: @Edward My mistake. It's the combination of [this article](https://bandestration.com/2015/10/26/whole-tube-and-half-tube-instruments-and-the-pedal-range) with the one you linked that clarifies. (Too many articles!) The issue on trumpet is that there are no pitches between the highest pedal tone (F) and the lowest true pitch (F#).

Comment: @Edward Okay, I think I found the problem. "Pedal tones" on a trumpet are something of a misnomer. 'trumpet players usually talk about the pitches between low F# and pedal C also as “pedal tones.” In contrast,  other brass players tend to call those “fake tones.”' [(Source)](https://wilktone.com/?p=4400).

Comment: @Aaron Well that's quite a discrepancy.  Good find.